# How is Isothermal compression work less than isentropic compression work?

Tags: thermodynamics

I know that isothermal compression work(input) is lesser than the isentropic/adiabatic compression work(input) for steady flow compressors. But does this also hold for positive displacement compressors (like piston-cylinder compressors)? I am asking as the area under the PV graph for the Isothermal compression process is greater than the adiabatic compression process.

[image]

[I am guessing this has to do with dV being negative here but can someone confirm this?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am asking as the area under the PV graph for the Isothermal
> compression process is greater than the adiabatic compression process.

The problem with your figures is neither involves the same volume change. Since you are interested in comparing the work done by both process, and work is the integral $\int_1^2pdV$ between the initial and final volume, you should probably compare them for the same volume change starting with the same initial pressure. See Fig 1 below.

Fig 1 compares an isothermal compression to an adiabatic compression that begin at the same pressure for the same volume change. Note that the magnitude of the work (area under the curve) is greater for the adiabatic process than the isothermal process. But since the work is done ***on the system***, the work is negative work.

Normally when we talk about more or less work being done we're generally referring to the work done ***by the system*** (expansion work), i.e., the magnitude of *positive* work. So in terms of the amount of work done by the system, more work is done for the isothermal compression in the sense that it is less negative (and therefore more positive) than the work done for the adiabatic compression.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: So for a steady flow system (VdP work) to compare the work done, we have to bring the system to the same pressure level and compare?

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking

Comment: If we have to compare the work done in a steady flow system (the work done is VdP), say, a steady flow compressor (axial flow compressor), do we bring the process line to the same  'pressure' level? (instead of the same volume level, as done in your answer for a positive displacement compressor)

Comment: Compare the work done to what?

Comment: Work done for 2 different compression processes (Isothermal vs Adiabatic) or compression with cooling and without cooling. But instead of work done in positive displacement compressor, I am wondering for a steady flow compression process, say steady flow isotherm and steady flow adiabatic.

Comment: I am wondering about my original question but with steady flow compression work (VdP)instead of in a positive displacement compression work(PdV). I know for steady flow process the area for work done is taken to the left of the PV graph (as it integral of VdP). So Fig1 and Fig2, but the area filled to the left of the isotherm and adiabatic curves.

Comment: @GRANZER I think you should post a new question since this goes beyond the original question involving PdV work of a closed system. That said, ideal compressors, pumps, turbines etc.., are considered reversible adiabatic processes. The work done by these open system devices is the difference in enthalpy between the inlet and outlet. The change in enthalpy includes the change in internal energy and change in the product of pressure and volume.  I am unaware of any steady flow systems involving isothermal work. If you do, you should provide an example with your question. Good luck.